# How to avoid extra 'extern' indent

Tags: c++, extern, indentation, astyle

I used astyle to format my C/C++ source codes, after many tries, it almost satisfied my need except that it added extra indent after the clause `extern "c" {`.

I find that astyle has this feature [here](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/news.html), it says "The C/C++ keyword 'extern' no longer causes an extra indent.", but do not find the option in its documentation.

I am using astyle 2.02.

Comment: it seems that there are few people using astyle, sign --

just another question, how to make just one tab indent of the second line for a two-line statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue was fixed some time ago, check out this bug link of AStyle:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3467479&group_id=2319&atid=102319

Comment: This link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is an open issue, see http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1514844&group_id=2319&atid=102319 for details.

That issue describes a potential workaround, however it requires modification of your source code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#if 0
}
#endif

void func1();

#if 0
{
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```